# PHP echo printing additional characters

Tags: php, echo

I can class myself as a mid level PHP user, I have recently installed XAMPP on a new PC and noticed a strange behaviour while trying to run a simple php script.
This is my script:

```
<?    
    $data_to = "<b>Line Print</b>";       
?>
<? echo($data_to); ?>
```

And this is what I am getting on the browser

> **Line Print"; ?>**

Can some one please explain why?

Comment: you sure there are only these lines in your page ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in php.ini and restart your Apache server.

**SOLUTION 2:**

Use the `<?php` tags completely because `<?` is not recommended.

If you ever have to move your code to a server where it's not supported (and you can't enable it), then you're doomed. It's better to use the full syntax.

Comment: Thank you both, you guys are superstars on Christmas day. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Short opening tags (`<?`) are disabled in php.ini. Either edit PHP configuration or use `<?php`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag